# Automatic documentation generation for Dymola code

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, dymola

since I could not find an answer to my question neither here nor in other forums, I decided to ask it to the community:

Does anybody know if and how it is possible to realize automatic documentation generation for code generated with Dymola?

The background for this e. g. is that I want/need to store additional information within my model files to explain the concepts of my modelling and to store and get the documentation directly from the model code, which I would later like to be in a convenient way displayable not only from within Dymola, but also by a html and LaTeX documentation.

I know that there exist several tools for automatic documentation generation like e. g. DoxyGen and Python Sphinx, but I could not figure out if the can be used with Dymola code. Plus, I am pretty new to this topic, so that I do not really know how to find out if they will work out.

Thank you people very much for your help!

Greetings, mindm49907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the Modelica model code, how does the HTML export in Dymola work for you? What's missing?

If you mean the C code generated by Dymola, the source code generation option enables more comments in the code.

Comment: Thank you Dag for your suggestions! I already tried the HTML export, and I'm not quite shure if it will fit my needs. I would like to have a more structured view of my model, with more options for highlightning of different parts, an easy-to-use math environment (the one of HTML is rather cumbersome, at least what I tried today...) and the possibility to get a kind of an inline-documentation at the end, while the HTML export function divides between code and documentation, which kind of doubles the work again ...

Comment: Hello Dag, I just received a more up-to-date version of Dymola (my former one was from 2007) and now everything I need works just fine, so of course you are right!